# Is it possible to control duplicate links in GOJS

Tags: gojs

I am implementing GOJS diagram something link as shown in below link

http://gojs.net/latest/samples/treeMapper.html

my question is, Is it possible to not allow duplicate links if any of the element on left /right side already has an link connected to it ?

Based on your initial answer,I have updated the code for nodeTemplate as below

```
 myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
              $(TreeNode,
                { movable: false },  // user cannot move an individual node
                // no Adornment: instead change panel background color by binding to Node.isSelected
                { selectionAdorned: false },
                { fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true,fromMaxLinks: 1,toMaxLinks:1 },  // user can draw link to and from such tree nodes
                $("TreeExpanderButton",  // support expanding/collapsing subtrees
                  { width: 14, height: 14,
                    "ButtonIcon.stroke": "black",
                    "ButtonIcon.strokeWidth": 2,
                    "ButtonBorder.fill": "whitesmoke",
                    "ButtonBorder.stroke": "black",
                    "ButtonBorder.figure": "Rectangle"
                  }),
                $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
                  { position: new go.Point(16, 0) },
                  new go.Binding("background", "isSelected", function(s) { return (s ? "lightblue" : "white"); }).ofObject(),

                  $(go.TextBlock,{ font: '9pt Verdana, sans-serif' },
                    new go.Binding("text", "Data", function(s) { return s; }))
                )  // end Horizontal Panel
              );  // end Node
```

Note: This is not just a tree implementation, This is tree implemented as part of Mapping field of records as shown in the link that i have shared.

all i want is each port should not have more than one link in the diagram[image]

that is container car of service params should not have more than one link to any other node in device model. similarly device in device model should not have more than one link coming from service params. similarly for all other nodes too.

Answer (score 1):

Improve the `checkLink` predicate as follows:

      `function checkLink(fn, fp, tn, tp, link) {
        // make sure the nodes are inside different Groups
        if (fn.containingGroup === null || fn.containingGroup.data.key !== -1) return false;
        if (tn.containingGroup === null || tn.containingGroup.data.key !== -2) return false;
        // optional limit to a single mapping link per node
        if (fn.linksConnected.any(function(l) { return l.category === "Mapping"; })) return false;
        if (tn.linksConnected.any(function(l) { return l.category === "Mapping"; })) return false;
        return true;
      }`

And change the node template to be smarter about the values for `fromLinkable` and `toLinkable`, instead of blindly setting them to true:

          `// whether the user can start drawing a link from or to this node depends on which group it's in
          new go.Binding("fromLinkable", "group", function(k) { return k === -1; }),
          new go.Binding("toLinkable", "group", function(k) { return k === -2; }),`

Don't bother using the `fromMaxLinks` and `toMaxLinks` properties, since that does not distinguish between the different kinds of links the Tree Mapper sample uses.

Read more about this at: http://gojs.net/latest/intro/validation.html and http://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html.

Comment: i dont think. it worked. let me update my question with the code and output diagram. Can you check and confirm where i am i doing wrong ?